# MySQL: check if a column has values based on another column

Tags: mysql

I'm using [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) to handle my database and I have one table:

```
Table:
id    sku    category
1     XYZ    Ballerinas
2            Ballerinas
3            Ballerinas
4     ABC    Ballerinas
```

As you can see I have `4` rows that are in the same category `Ballerinas`, but two of them don't have an `sku`. How can I return those rows using a PDO query only if **all** `Ballerinas` have an `sku`?

Thank you! :D

Comment: those rows have `null` value or empty value? what's the default value for that column?

Comment: those columns have empty string `sku = ''`

Comment: `where sku is not null and trim(sku) <> ''`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to find matching categories is to aggregate by category and then assert the total count matches the count of `sku` values which are *not* empty string.  If these two counts match, then retain that category.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT category
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY category
    HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN sku <> '' THEN 1 END)
) t2
    ON t1.category = t2.category;
```

### Demo

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen, this is perfeeeecttttt, it does exactly what i need! :D Thank youuuuuuu! :D<3

Comment: Yes @TimBiegeleisen, this answer solved my problem i just had to wait 10 minutes before i could mark it :D. Thank you again! :D

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do it without a join:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t2 WHERE t1.category = t2.category AND t2.sku IS NULL);
```

If you consider empty values ('') also as "not being a value" then the condition in the `exists` clause should be

```
where t2.category=t1.category and not t2.SKU>''
```

Comment: In the columns list of the outer query you don’t need to specify the table alias (`t1.`), since only one table is available for output.

Comment: Thank you @cars10m, i've already used Tim's answer but this one works too :D