# Fetch data from one table and compare with another one basic on contain values

Tags: php, mysql

I got 2 different databases and 2 tables

Here's `Table.1`:

```
Table.1
username | date | phone number | rank                   |
user1    | 2021 | xxx xxx xxxx | ALL                    |
user2    | 2021 | xxx xxx xxxx | river, domain, CW, road|
user3    | 2021 | xxx xxx xxxx | river, CW              |
user4    | 2021 | xxx xxx xxxx | owl, gold, moon, DD    |
```

and there's Table.2

```
Table 2
rank    | CODE | locations | contain | price  | exp |
river   | WT-2 | xxx xxx xx| JRCOW20 | 500.00 | --- |
road    | CC2W | xxx xxx xx| ------- | 200.00 | --- |
owl     | 568T | xxx xxx xx| JCCW120 | 300.00 | --- |
owl     | CCCD | xxx xxx xx| CWFGTFF | 100.00 | --- |
CW      | PTR1 | xxx xxx xx| 09WWKAL | 100.00 | --- |
CW      | 1RRW | xxx xxx xx| WFR4444 | 300.00 | --- |
```

but the users ask for all items separately according

searching the **ranking**.**values** using `Table.2` and compare with `Table.1`

How can I use Sql command having the result when
something like :

login as `user2` so I would get

```
rank    | CODE | locations | contain | price  | exp |
river   | WT-2 | xxx xxx xx| JRCOW20 | 500.00 | --- |
road    | CC2W | xxx xxx xx| ------- | 200.00 | --- |
CW      | PTR1 | xxx xxx xx| 09WWKAL | 100.00 | --- |
CW      | 1RRW | xxx xxx xx| WFR4444 | 300.00 | --- |
```

but if when the user login as `user4`
than I would get

```
rank    | CODE | locations | contain | price  | exp |
owl     | 568T | xxx xxx xx| JCCW120 | 300.00 | --- |
owl     | CCCD | xxx xxx xx| CWFGTFF | 100.00 | --- |
```

I try to figure out the SQL parts
and the following works has been tested;
but no luck:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [DB-1].[Table.1]
JOIN 
    [DB-2].[Table.2]
WHERE
    [DB-2].[Table.2] 
IN
    (
    [DB-1].[Table.1].[Col-Rank]
    )
```

but so far some of them come out either empty,
of just output single result as:

```
login as *user2* result:
user2    | 2021 | xxx xxx xxxx | river, domain, CW, road|
river    | WT-2 | xxx xxx xxxx | JRCOW20 | 500.00 | --- |
```

or

```
login as *user4* result:
user4    | 2021 | xxx xxx xxxx | owl, gold, moon, DD    |
owl      | 568T | xxx xxx xxxx | JCCW120 | 300.00 | --- |
```

I don't understand where should I change the detail
and honestly this is very new problem to me

currently using MySQl 7.4, by PhpMyAdmin
also PHP 7.4

There could be a lot informal statement come out of PhpMyAdmin;
still trying to make everything work;
any help would be appreciate!

---

Below are the questions I have tried:

[sql-query-multiple-records-against-one-column-value-need-to-compare-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226514/sql-query-multiple-records-against-one-column-value-need-to-compare-another)

[mysql-check-if-a-column-has-values-based-on-another-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362445/mysql-check-if-a-column-has-values-based-on-another-column)

[mysql-how-to-check-for-a-value-in-all-columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/248830/mysql-how-to-check-for-a-value-in-all-columns)

Comment: The design of `Table.1` should store each user rank in it's own row instead of `ALL` or comma-separated values. The current design makes it harder to construct the query and possibly will impact the performance. If you can re-design the table, then, you should do it. Anyway, what MySQL version are you using?

Comment: MySQL version is 7.4, also PHP 7.4
and I think you guys are right, we should change the design

Comment: I think you're mistaken with the MySQL version because there's no v7.4. You can check the version by running this query `SELECT version();` You should get a result [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0).

Comment: Got the version(): 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3,
Yup that make me understanding as the version of system, since link with ubuntu

Comment: Great! I see you've decided to change the table design. Once you've done that, construct a workable query then you can post an answer (and probably accept it too) on your own question. I'm looking forward to what you come up with :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this just works fine,
according of the WHERE ... IN ();

also the results of rank comes from another application, honestly I haven't had the clue to ask for it with another team

`signal` as Table.2
I used same method as
[MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `signal`
WHERE
    `rank` IN(
        'river',
        'domain',
        'CW',
        'road'
    );
```

but I work it in the PHP file, so that's why it may look won't work as expect

```
PHP file
$sig = str_replace(',' , '','', $_SESSION['sig']);
```

or

```
$sig = str_replace(',' , '","', $_SESSION['sig']);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `WHERE IN()` definitely does not work as you intend when you have delimited strings in a column.  This will not work for the sample data that you have offered.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/2943403

Comment: `IN()` might work on Table 2, but it won't work on Table 1.  Maybe `FIND_IN_SET()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string  `signal` isn't mentioned anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 0):

IMO `rank` (i.e. 'river, domain, CW, road') should be an extra table.

Or you may can use `REGEXP`. But i think this would cost a lot resources. *Im not an expert.*

Example (UNTESTED):

```
SELECT
    `tbl2`.*
FROM `Table1` AS `tbl1`
JOIN `Table2` AS `tbl2` ON `tbl2`.`rank` REGEXP REPLACE(`tb1`.`rank`,', ','|')
WHERE `username` = :username
;
```

Plan is to "find" the user in the table 1 by name,

and then join table 2 on `rank`

using `REGEXP` to check if the row matches f.e. 'river|domain|CW|road'

('river' OR 'domain' OR 'CW' OR 'road').

*The REPLACE is to get the `,`  to an `|`.*

*But like i said - im not an expert =)*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get the point of suggest change the structure of *RANK*
I'm gonna test those solution right now